# Python ctypes structure being overwritten when allocating more memory

Tags: python, ctypes

In Python 3.2 I am creating a Structure object from the data returned by the ctypes.windll.kernel32.DeviceIoControl function. After this is done I can access the Structure fields and return the data. However, if i do something the uses a memory, such as opening a file the data inside the structure is modified. In the first part of the output that I have pasted in the results are what is to be expected. However, after a file is opened and the structures fields printed again values have been changed. I am not sure why the data is being modified or how to stop it from happening.

Structures:

```
class DISK_GEOMETRY(ctypes.Structure):
    '''
    Disk Geometry Data Structure
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363972(v=vs.85).aspx
    '''
    _fields_ = [("Cylinders", wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ("MediaType", wintypes.BYTE), #MEDIA_TYPE
                ("TracksPerCylinder", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("SectorsPerTrack", wintypes.DWORD),
                ("BytesPerSector", wintypes.DWORD)]


class DISK_GEOMETRY_EX(ctypes.Structure):
    '''
    Disk Geometry EX Data Structure
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363970(v=vs.85).aspx
    '''
    _fields_ = [("Geometry", DISK_GEOMETRY),
                ("DiskSize", wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ("Data[1]", wintypes.BYTE)]
```

DeviceIoControl:

```
class DeviceIoControl:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def __DeviceIoControl(self, devicehandle, IoControlCode, input, output):
        '''
        DeviceIoControl Function
        http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx
        '''
        DevIoCtl = ctypes.windll.kernel32.DeviceIoControl
        DevIoCtl.argtypes = [
            wintypes.HANDLE, #HANDLE hDevice
            wintypes.DWORD, #DWORD dwIoControlCode
            wintypes.LPVOID, #LPVOID lpInBuffer
            wintypes.DWORD, #DWORD nInBufferSize
            wintypes.LPVOID, #LPVOID lpOutBuffer
            wintypes.DWORD, #DWORD nOutBufferSize
            ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.DWORD), #LPDWORD lpBytesReturned
            wintypes.LPVOID] #LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
        DevIoCtl.restype = wintypes.BOOL

        if isinstance(output, int):
            output = ctypes.create_string_buffer(output)

        input_size = len(input) if input is not None else 0
        output_size = len(output)
        assert isinstance(output, ctypes.Array)

        BytesReturned = wintypes.DWORD()

        status = DevIoCtl(devicehandle, IoControlCode, input, input_size, output, output_size, BytesReturned, None)
        return output[:BytesReturned.value] if status is not 0 else -1

    def GetDriveGeometry(self):
        diskhandle = winapi.CreateHandle(
                self.path,
                winapi.NULL,
                winapi.FILE_SHARE_READ|winapi.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                winapi.LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(),
                winapi.OPEN_EXISTING,
                winapi.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                winapi.NULL)
        if diskhandle == winapi.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
            return -1

        temp = ctypes.cast(self.__DeviceIoControl(diskhandle, winioctl.IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX, None, 1024), ctypes.POINTER(winioctl.DISK_GEOMETRY_EX)).contents
        winapi.CloseHandle(diskhandle)
        return temp
```

Main:

```
device = DeviceIoControl(r"\\.\PhysicalDrive0")
devicegeo = device.GetDriveGeometry()
print("Disk Size: " +str(devicegeo.DiskSize))
print("BytesPerSector: "+str(devicegeo.Geometry.BytesPerSector))
print("Cylinders: "+str(devicegeo.Geometry.Cylinders))
print("MediaType: "+str(hex(devicegeo.Geometry.MediaType)))
print("CtypesAddressOf: "+str(ctypes.addressof(devicegeo)))

with open(r"\\.\PhysicalDrive0", 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(0)
    MBRdata = f.read(512)
print("\nOpened a file\n")        

print("Disk Size: "+str(devicegeo.DiskSize))
print("BytesPerSector: "+str(devicegeo.Geometry.BytesPerSector))
print("Cylinders: "+str(devicegeo.Geometry.Cylinders))
print("MediaType: "+str(hex(devicegeo.Geometry.MediaType)))
print("CtypesAddressOf: "+str(ctypes.addressof(devicegeo)))
```

Output:

```
Disk Size: 80000000000
BytesPerSector: 512
Cylinders: 9726
MediaType: 0xc
CtypesAddressOf: 12322040

Opened a file

Disk Size: 0
BytesPerSector: 1
Cylinders: 2170477562872987649
MediaType: -0x40
CtypesAddressOf: 12322040
```

Comment: Depends on what `device` is and what its `GetDriveGeometry` does (or, precisely, what `ctypes` facilitates in its returned value). It could be that the underlying native implementation returns a view of memory that it manages, and you're not meant to own them.

Comment: @Santa I added the code behind those functions to the question.

Comment: @Shawn Where is `winapi` import come from? Is it an alias to some imported package?

Comment: okay, founded. I use `win32con` instead, and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations:

1. `DevIoCtl` should be called with `byref(BytesReturned)`.
2. `ctypes.cast`'s first argument must be an "object that can be interpreted as a pointer".
   What you are casting, however, is a raw `bytes` object (from `output[:BytesReturned.value]`).
3. At this point, what you returned from `__DeviceIoControl` is a new Python `bytes` object. The original reference to ctypes array object has gone out of scope. So, it's entirely possible that it has been garbage collected and/or reused.

FWIW, I played around with Windows IOCTL dispatch using ctypes just for the heck of it. Also using `\\.\PysicalDrive0` and `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY`.

I made [this gist](https://gist.github.com/santa4nt/11068180).