# Casting a bytearray instance in ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

When developing in pycharm, the code below sometimes fails (the contents of the casted structure changes) when I run a coverage unit test, but not when running it as a unit test. The following is the relevant part of the code:

```
class SomeStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('field', ctypes.c_char)
    ]

res = bytearray(b'12345')
ctypes.cast(bytes(res), ctypes.POINTER(SomeStruct)).contents
```

However the following always works:

```
class SomeStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('field', ctypes.c_char)
    ]

res = bytearray(b'12345')
res_bytes = bytes(res)
ctypes.cast(res_bytes, ctypes.POINTER(SomeStruct)).contents
```

This seems to me like some reference counting problem, however I'm not sure. Why does this problem occur? And what is the proper way to cast a bytearray instance in ctypes?

The python version is 3.4.0, x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following answer helped:
[Python ctypes structure being overwritten when allocating more memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669074/python-ctypes-structure-being-overwritten-when-allocating-more-memory?rq=1)

```
class SomeStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('field', ctypes.c_char)
    ]

res = bytearray(b'12345')
ctypes.cast(ctypes.create_string_buffer(bytes(res)), ctypes.POINTER(SomeStruct)).contents
```